# Slicing with python on a single line

Tags: python, line, slice

I have data "line"

```
FF= ['123451234512345678901234512345', '123451234512345678901234512345']
```

I need to slice line 1-5, 6-10, 11, 12-22. How do I slice?

```
data= [] 

for col in FF:
    data.append(col)
```

Comment: When you say line do you mean character? For the given input what is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
a = [(s[:5], s[5:10], s[10], s[11:]) for s in FF]
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).

```
>>> struct.unpack('5s5sc11s8x', '123451234512345678901234512345')
('12345', '12345', '1', '23456789012')
```